# Database is not showing on SSMS Object Explorer

Tags: azure, sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database

A couple of days ago I set up Azure Database Sync in order to keep the backup DB and the primary one synced. But after doing that, the database used as a hub is no longer visible on SSMS Object Explorer. If I stop the DB Sync, it shows up normally. I have admin rights on the database. The problem is that if I have to check anything on the database, now I cannot. Has anyone any advice about this issue?

**UPDATE:**
For everyone facing the same issue, one workaround is to open the database via Visual Studio. in VS, the database is listed as it should be

Comment: What version of SSMS are you using? There was a similar issue my Azure DBs not showing up in SSMS but I no longer encounter it with the latest updates:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

Comment: I had a similar issue, and applying the latest updates to SSMS took care of the problem

Comment: I have SSMS 2014, and I apply updates in regular way... Is it a n issue related to this version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying getting the latest SSMS will most likely solve this problem.

[msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx)